# The meaning of "a cottage industry of people"

Tags: meaning

What does "a cottage industry of people" in the following [Washington Post article](http://articles.washingtonpost.com/2013-08-25/politics/41446527_1_presidential-race-new-hampshire-vice-president-biden) mean?

> All of the early machinations by Republicans and Democrats who want to be the next president — even though President Obama won reelection just 292 days ago — have spawned a cottage industry of people wondering whether this is the earliest start ever for a presidential race and whether that’s a good or a bad thing.

Comment: The key phrase is *[cottage industry](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/cottage+industry)*.

Comment: Like choster said, the meaning is in the meaning of the phrase.  The idea is that people who normally wouldn't get involved in the 'industry' of elections are now getting deeply invested and involved at home.

Comment: The name came from the 18th and 19th centuries, when artisans made goods in their homes - cottages, goods that were intended to be better than factory-produced items.  By extension (as here), it can cover a large number of people working on a similar task (in this case, wondering).  And in this case, it may not pay well.

Comment: It's not a very well-chosen turn of phrase either, because "cottage industry" is supposed to refer to a business practice, where this implies that 'wondering' is in itself a business, and a very particular form of wondering too.  If the author means to imply a cottage industry of political pundits, then that is what they have implied.  Otherwise it's hard to imagine any sort of industry in which wondering would be the chief occupation.

Comment: See also: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52230/cottage-cheese-so-called-to-differentiate-from-expensive-cheese

Answer (score 0):

"...spawned a cottage industry of people wondering..." means that the outcome of the election caused a cottage industry to form, and this cottage industry is an industry that speculates about the next presidential race.  Check out the meaning of cottage industry.  It isn't "of people" it is "of people wondering".

A "cottage industry" consists of an uncentralized and unorganized effort to produces goods at home for sale.  The article is attempting to imply that everyone speculating about this subject are amateurs who may not really know what they're talking about.